# How to query another Objects field to get it's value

Tags: soql, unit-test, query, sobject

How do I query the value of Contact.Country__c? It is to be connected with Case.

For now my code is:

```
@isTest
public class WebToCaseCountryTest
{


    public static testMethod void testTrigger()
    {
        Area__c ar = new Area__c(Name = 'CA');
        insert ar;

        Case caseObj = new Case(CountryWebFormText__c ='CA', Newsletter__c = TRUE);
        insert caseObj;
        caseObj=[Select id,countryWebFormText__c,Country_of_Origin__r.name from Case where id=:caseObj.id limit 1];
        System.debug('CountryWebFormText__c' + caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c);
        System.debug('Country_of_Origin__c' + caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c);

        Contact cont = new Contact(id=caseOb.Contactid, FirstName='Mr. Test', LastName='Contact');
        insert cont;

        cont = [SELECT id, Country__r.name from Contact WHERE Id =: caseObj.ContactId];
        System.debug('Country__r.Name' + cont.Country__c);

        System.assertEquals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c, caseObj.Country_of_Origin__r.name);        

    }
}
```

This is the Trigger:

```
trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (after insert)
{

    Set<String> countries = new Set<String>();
    for (Case c : Trigger.new)
    {
        if (!String.isEmpty(c.CountryWebFormText__c) && c.Newsletter__c == TRUE)
        {
            countries.add(c.CountryWebFormText__c);
        }
    }

    if (countries.size() > 0)
    {
        Map<String, Id> filteredCountries = new Map<String, Id>();
        for (Area__c a : [select Name, Id from Area__c where Name in :countries])
        {
            filteredCountries.put(a.Name, a.Id);
        }
        if (filteredCountries.size() > 0)
        {
            List<Case> caseUpdates = new List <Case>();
            List<Contact> contactUpdates = new List <Contact>();
            for (Case c : Trigger.new)
            {
                if (filteredCountries.containsKey(c.CountryWebFormText__c))
                {
                    Id areaId = filteredCountries.get(c.CountryWebFormText__c);
                    caseUpdates.add(new Case(Id = c.Id, Country_of_Origin__c = areaId));
                    if (c.ContactId != null)
                    {
                        contactUpdates.add(new Contact(Id = c.ContactId, Country__c = areaId));
                    }
                }
            }
            update caseUpdates;
            update contactUpdates;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `caseObj=[Select id,  Contact.Country__c,    countryWebFormText__c,Country_of_Origin__r.name from Case where id=:caseObj.id limit 1];`

Comment: When I use System.debug('Country__c + caseObj.Contact.Country__c); it returns Null?

Comment: Where in test class or trigger?

Comment: In the test class, right under the caseObj statement you suggested

Comment: In test class you never provided value to `Country__c` so, it would be `null`

Comment: Ashwani is right you need to provide Country value in Contact cont = new Contact... line. Becuase you did not do it, it will always be null.

Comment: I wasn't clear on this point but in my trigger the Contact.Country__c field should be equal to Case.CountryWebFormText__c. So in my test, shouldn't this field have a value? Unless it means my trigger is not working correctly

Comment: @Nik yes! check your trigger now.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani though I'm not sure why the Country__c field is not updating? I have added my trigger to the post. Could this line be the problem if (filteredCountries.containsKey(c.CountryWebFormText__c))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to provide contact ID to Case in test method:

```
public static testMethod void testTrigger()
    {
        Area__c ar = new Area__c(Name = 'CA');
        insert ar;

        Contact conts = new Contact( FirstName='Mr. Test2', LastName='Contact2');
        insert conts;
        Case caseObj = new Case(ContactId=conts.id,CountryWebFormText__c ='CA', Newsletter__c = TRUE);
        insert caseObj;
        caseObj=[Select id,ContactID, Contact.Country__c, countryWebFormText__c,Country_of_Origin__r.name from Case where id=:caseObj.id limit 1];
        System.debug('CountryWebFormText__c' + caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c);
        System.debug('Country_of_Origin__c' + caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c);

        Contact cont = new Contact(id=caseOb.Contactid, FirstName='Mr. Test', LastName='Contact');
        upsert cont;

        cont = [SELECT id, Country__r.name from Contact WHERE Id =: caseObj.ContactId];
        System.debug('Country__r.Name' + cont.Country__c);

        System.assertEquals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c, caseObj.Country_of_Origin__r.name);        

    }
```

Case record created in test method don't have ContactID and in your trigger you are checking contactId as:

```
   if (c.ContactId != null)
   {
      contactUpdates.add(new Contact(Id = c.ContactId, Country__c = areaId));
   }
```

Comment: There is an error with this code, that I have gotten before: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.ContactId

Comment: @Nik updated the answer